# Placing JButtons at exact locations and creating grid of JLabels?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jlabel, layout-manager

```
public class SudukoGUI extends JPanel{
    
    private static int WIDTH;
    private static int HEIGHT;
    private static int PANEL_HEIGHT;
    
    public SudukoGUI(int width, int height, String title) {
        this.WIDTH = width;
        this.HEIGHT = height;
        this.PANEL_HEIGHT = height - width;
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> initGUI(WIDTH, HEIGHT, title));
    }
    
    public int getWidth() {
        return WIDTH;
    }
    
    public int getHeight() {
        return HEIGHT;
    }
    
    public void initGUI(int width, int height, String title) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);
        JButton b1 = new JButton("Solve");
        JButton b2 = new JButton("Clear");
        
//      JPanel bp = new JPanel();
//      bp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
//      bp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, PANEL_HEIGHT));
//      frame.add(bp);
        
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.add(b1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        this.add(b2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setSize(width + 16, height);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.add(this);
        //frame.pack();
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        
        g2d.setColor(new Color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f));
        
        int cellWidth = WIDTH / Suduko.getNumRows();
        int cellHeight = (HEIGHT - PANEL_HEIGHT) / Suduko.getNumCols();
        int gridHeight = HEIGHT - PANEL_HEIGHT;
        int regionWidth = 3, regionHeight = 3;
                
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        
        g2d.setColor(new Color(0,0,0));
        for(int i = 0; i <= WIDTH; i += cellWidth) {
            if((i / cellWidth) % regionWidth == 0) {
                g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
                g2d.drawLine(i, 0, i, gridHeight);
            }else {
                g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1));
                g2d.drawLine(i, 0, i, gridHeight);
            }
        }
        
        for(int i = 0; i <= gridHeight; i += cellHeight) {
            if((i / cellHeight) % regionHeight == 0) {
                g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
                g2d.drawLine(0, i, WIDTH, i);
            }else {
                g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1));
                g2d.drawLine(0,  i, WIDTH, i);
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

[image]

As of now both buttons are at `BorderLayout.SOUTH`. I don't know how to place them at the bottom of this window and in smaller sizes. I tried creating a separate `JPanel` with `setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, PANEL_HEIGHT));` So it would be the blank area at the bottom, but that doesn't work of course, when changing the border layout the buttons take up the entire height. I want to place the buttons at the bottom in the blank area.

I also want to create `JLabel` components for the grid so I can enter numbers with `KeyListener` (and having `MouseListener` for selecting which cell). I'm not sure here how to proceed how to create labels in a grid format and how to set exact sizes to them etc. Any tips?

Comment: *"Any tips?"* 1) Don't use slang like 'wanna'. The term is 'want to'. 2) Practice more on combining different layouts. I see a 3x3 grid layout of panels, each with a 3x3 grid layout of .. whatever component is inside those panels. Add the outer grid layout to the `CENTER` of a border layout. To the `PAGE_END` constraint, add a panel with flow layout or grid bag layout. Add the buttons to that. 3) *"how to proceed how to create labels in a grid format[a] and how to set exact sizes to them[b]"* a) grid layout as mentioned earlier. b) Don't. They need to be square? Extend the component ..

Comment: .. and override the `getPreferredSize()` method to return a dimension that is the larger of width or height, for both the width **and** height.

Comment: Why doesn't setPreferredSize set the panels to the size I want?

Comment: It appears that you're making a sudoku grid.  It's much easier to create a drawing `JPanel` with a `MouseListener` to display and change numbers.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  The [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) lesson will show you how to create a drawing `JPanel`.

Comment: *"Why doesn't setPreferredSize set the panels to the size I want?"* A layout manager will take the preferred size as *a hint,* and in *some cases* will use it. For examples: 1) A `GridLayout` will make the cell size as wide as the widest component, and as tall as the tallest. Every other component in the cells will be stretched to fit. 2) A border layout will stretch for the center constraint, stretch height for the line start & end constraints, and stretch width for the page start & end constraints. 3) A flow layout will respect the preferred width and height. ..

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I don't understand how paintComponents work in realation to other components it seems like I cant add things on top of the pC method...

Comment: I would not use a drawing panel for this. For a sududo grid it is easy enough to use  JTextFields to make it easy to enter values into the grid. Concentrate on creating your panel using a GridLayout. When you create your Sududo panel you should specify the size of each grid. Then override the `getPreferredSize()` of your panel to return the preferred size of the panel which would simply be the size of each cell * 9. Once all the components are added to the frame you then `pack()` the frame to make sure each component is displayed properly.

Comment: When you create the GridLayout you can specify the space between components and make the background of your panel black so by default your grid lines will be painted. *I also want to create JLabel components for the grid so I can enter numbers with KeyListener (and having MouseListener for selecting which cell)* - what about people who want to use the keyboard? I would just use JTextFields. Then you can tab from cell to cell or use the mouse.

Comment: You can't have two different components at the same `BorderLayout.*` position. If you need two buttons in the bottom panel, place them inside a `JPanel`. If you want there to be blank space around buttons, try using `BoxLayout` for the bottom panel and add the glue on either side of buttons using `Box.createGlue()`.

Comment: @camickr Is there a way to get different sized gaps in the GridLayout? To achive the Sudoku-look?

Comment: *"get different sized gaps in the GridLayout"* No, but you can use a 3x3 of 3x3 gird layouts to create the effect of a Soduko board, as I mentioned in the first comment.. The 'outer' grid layout can be assigned more space between each of the panels (each with their own grid layouts with less space) for the effect.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Did that and it worked nicely. I did a new question regarding how to translate the coordinate issue that arises next. Any ideas here?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71298651/translating-coordinates-from-9-layouts-within-a-larger-one-to-two-dimensional-a

Answer (score 1):

You can use a 3x3 grid of 3x3 grid layouts to create the effect of a Soduko board. The 'outer' grid layout can be assigned more space between each of the panels (each with its own grid layout with less space) for the effect.

[image]

Here is how that screenshot was created, adjust numbers (colors etc) to suit the exact requirement.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class SudokuBoard {

    public SudokuBoard() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public final void initComponents() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,3,6,6));
        panel.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(3,3,3,3));
        int s = 20;
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(s,s,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image);
        for (int ii=0; ii<9; ii++) {
            JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,3,2,2));
            p.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
            for (int jj=0; jj<9; jj++) {
                JLabel l = new JLabel(icon);
                p.add(l);
            }
            panel.add(p);
        }

        JFrame f = new JFrame("Sudoku");
        f.add(panel);
        f.setResizable(false);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new SudokuBoard();
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```