# Translating coordinates from 9 layouts within a larger one, to two-dimensional array?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

So I have a Sudoku grid which consists of one large 3x3 GridLayout and each of its elements consists of a smaller 3x3 GridLayout of JTextFields. My issue here is that my Sudoku will be in the form of a 2D array but the layout structure does not look the same. The image below shows how the coordinates look like in the layout form. My question is if and then how I can "translate" the coordinates from array form to "layout"-form?

(I guess a problem could be that the outer GridLayout loops 9 times linearly while the inner ones loop 3x3 in 2D)

[image]

```
        int[][] matrix = s.getMatrix();
        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        
        gl.setHgap(4);
        gl.setVgap(4);
        p1.setBackground(Color.black);
        p1.setSize(WIDTH, (HEIGHT - PANEL_HEIGHT));
        p1.setLayout(gl);
                
        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            JPanel p = new JPanel();
            GridLayout local_gl = new GridLayout(3,3);
            local_gl.setHgap(2);
            local_gl.setVgap(2);
            p.setBackground(Color.black);
            p.setSize(WIDTH / 3, (HEIGHT - PANEL_HEIGHT) / 3);
            p.setLayout(local_gl);
            
            p1.add(p);
            
            for(int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
                for(int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
                    JTextField jtf = new JTextField("  " + Integer.toString(matrix[row][col]));
                    if(jtf.getText().trim().equals("0")) {
                        jtf.setText("  ");
                    }
                    jtf.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 30));
                    p.add(jtf);
                }
            }
        }
```

---

This solution works.

```
JTextField jtf = new JTextField("  " + Integer.toString(matrix[translateRowToY(i, row)][translateColToX(i, col)]));
```

```
private int translateColToX(int i, int col) {
        if(i == 2 || i == 5 || i == 8) {
            return col + 6;
        }else if(i == 1 || i == 4 || i == 7) {
            return col + 3;
        }else if(i == 0 || i == 3 || i == 6) {
            return col;
        }else {
            return -1;  
        }
    }
    
private int translateRowToY(int i, int row) {
        if(i >= 0 && i < 3) {
            return row;
        }else if(i >= 3 && i < 6) {
            return row + 3;
        }else if(i >= 6 && i < 9) {
            return row + 6;
        }else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not use 9 panels with 9 inputs each; instead, I would use single panel with 81 inputs, arranged in a 9x9 grid. Instead of `JTextFields`, I would define a `public static class SudokuCell extends JTextField`, so that, each time you create a new cell, you can keep all its tracking information inside:

```
  public static class SudokuCell extends JTextField {
   
      public final int block; // 0 to 9, you call it `i`
      public final int row;   // 0 to 9 again
      public final int col;   // again 0-9

      public SudokuCell(int block, int row, int col) {
           // ... assign to attributes
      }
  }
```

The advantage is that interpreting clicks is now trivial: if you add a `MouseListener` to each of those cells, `c.row` will tell you the row it is on, `c.block` will reply with the block, and so on and so forth.

Initializing those cells is also very easy:

```
  for (int row=0; row<DIM; row++) {
     for (int col=0; col<DIM; col++) {
        SudokuCell c = new SudokuCell((row/3)*3 + col/3, row, col);
        // add to panel for display, and to internal DIMxDIM array too.
     }
  }
```

Comment: Problem is there's no distinction between the 9 separate regions. I had a single panel with 9x9 at first but I also wanted to distinguish the separate regions so therefore I made it this way.

Comment: But this was a useful tip, thank you!

Comment: There is as much distinction as you want to add. If you have a `JPanel` with a 9x9 `GridLayout`, you can override its `paintChildren` method, call `super.paintChildren()`, and add the 4 extra lines where you want them to be (easy because you can check the bounds of each cell).